# How to determine if a selection in a contenteditable DIV is from left-to-right or from right-to-left

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Within a contenteditable DIV, I want to determine, if the user made a selection from left-to-right or from right-to-left. Does someone have a Javascript solution for the Browsers Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera? And when possible, also one for IE?

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable>
Selection from Cursor end | here <strong>over bold</strong> to Cursor start | here.
</div>
```

I prepared the code in jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ecUka/

Thank's in advance :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a function that uses the fact that setting the end of a DOM Range to be at an earlier point in the document than the start of the range will collapse the range.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/97MDR/17/

Code:

```
function isSelectionBackwards() {
    var backwards = false;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
            range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
            backwards = range.collapsed;
        }
    }
    return backwards;
}
```

Demo:

```js
function isSelectionBackwards() {
    var backwards = false;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
            range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
            backwards = range.collapsed;
        }
    }
    return backwards;
}

document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function() {
  document.getElementById("selReport").textContent = isSelectionBackwards();
});
```

```html
<p>Select something forwards and backwards in here</p>
<p>Selection is backwards: <strong id="selReport">false</strong><p>
```

**Unless you need to support Internet Explorer <9, which seems highly unlikely in 2023, you can safely ignore the rest of this answer, which I'm leaving here for posterity.**

---

The above works in all major browsers except IE < 9, which does not support the same Range and Selection APIs as other browsers.

For IE < 9, there is simply nothing in the selection API to tell you about the selection direction. The best I can suggest is using the [`selectionchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event to  keep track of the previously selected range and see which end has changed each time it fires. It seems to work in the following example but has had no testing apart from that, so use at your own risk.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/97MDR/18/

Additional code specific to IE < 9 that won't work in modern browsers:

```
var selectedRange, selectionBackwards;

document.onselectionchange = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var sel = document.selection;
    if (sel && sel.type !== "Control") {
        if (sel.type == "Text") {
            // Selection is not collapsed, so compare range end points
            var newRange = sel.createRange();
            if (selectedRange) {
                var startChanged = (newRange.compareEndPoints("StartToStart", selectedRange) != 0);
                var endChanged = (newRange.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", selectedRange) != 0);

                if (startChanged && !endChanged) {
                    selectionBackwards = true;
                } else if (endChanged && !startChanged) {
                    selectionBackwards = false;
                } else if (startChanged && endChanged) {
                    // Both ends have changed, which is confusing.
                    // I suspect this can happen when the selection snaps
                    // to words. In this case we can tell nothing, so leave
                    // selectionBackwards alone.
                } else {
                    // Neither end has changed, so we can tell nothing.
                }
            }
            
            selectedRange = newRange;
        } else {
            // Selection is collapsed
            selectionBackwards = false;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for :-) Does someone have also a solution for Internet Explorer Versions 6, 7 and 8?

Comment: @Max: Unless there's something very obscure I've never found after some looking, it's not possible in 6-8. There is simply nothing in the JavaScript API that can be used to get the selection direction.

Comment: @Max: You may be able to do something by observing the [`selectionchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event (e.g. keeping track of the previously selected range and seeing which end has changed)

Comment: @Max: I've come up with something that seems to work in the very limited test case I've tried it on. See my updated answer.

Comment: Checking `range.collapsed` looks simpler than `compareDocumentPosition`.

Comment: `range.collapsed` doesn't show if the selection was from right to left or reverse

Comment: This does not work in 2023

Comment: @Marian07: Do you mean the `isSelectionBackwards()` function? If so, it's working fine for me in everything I've tried. There haven't been any DOM/HTML API changes that mean it shouldn't work.

Comment: @TimDown, `document.selection` does not exist, `document.getSelection()` is for getting the selection. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getSelection . Here is a solution for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23512678/3102325

Comment: @Marian07: As mentioned in the answer, the part with `document.selection` is only for IE < 9, which is unlikely to be relevant to anyone but a tiny number of people now. Maybe I should make that clearer in the answer.

Comment: @TimDown, got it! Probably.

Answer (score 0):

```html
range.setStart(anchorNode, anchorOffset);
range.setEnd(focusNode, focusOffset);
if(range.collapsed == false){
colsole.log('forward Selected');
}else{
colsole.log('backward Selected');
}
```