# How to get selection direction in HTML?

Tags: html, selection

Documentation about Selection reports

> A user may make a selection from left to right (in document order) or right to left (reverse of document order).

[Documentation about Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)

How it is possible to distinguish the two cases, getting if the user selected starting from the begin or from the end? And if the user selected with a double click?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180405/detect-direction-of-user-selection-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Actually, depending on direction of selection you have selection start and end in sequence or not (reverse). So creating a range with these boundaries and checking if it collapsed, gives the information needed. (Implementation in javascript)

```
function selectionIsBackwards(){
  var sel = window.getSelection();

  let range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
  range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);

  let backwards = range.collapsed;
  range.detach();
  return backwards;
}
```